# To Connect MySql database from android my app ,It does not connect with php file shows error

Tags: android

I want to connect to a MySQL database in Android and what I have tried is not working. My PHP file is okay, I have checked it many times. The error message I get when I click on the login button is this one.

```
Exception: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1(port80):connect failed: ECONNREFUSED(Connection Refused)
```

Here is my code to connect with PHP file to insert data

```
package com.broken.nezamulislamar.mysqlblog_1;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
private TextView statusField,roleField;
private Context context;
private int byGetOrPost = 0;

//flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView statusField,TextView roleField,int flag) {
    this.context = context;
    //this.statusField = statusField;
    //this.roleField = roleField;
    byGetOrPost = flag;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    if(byGetOrPost == 0){ //means by Get Method

        try{
            String username = (String)arg0[0];
            String password = (String)arg0[1];
            String link = "http://127.0.0.1/Client    /jakir.php?username="+username+"& password="+password;

            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line="";

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else{
        try{
            String username = (String)arg0[0];
            String password = (String)arg0[1];

            String link="http://127.0.0.1/Client/jakir.php?";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    this.statusField.setText("Login Successful");
    this.roleField.setText(result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've connected to localhost. I.E your Android device, not the server.

You can use `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` or whatever your operating system uses to find the ipv4 of the server on the local network.

For example, maybe `192.168.1.100`

Comment: I use php file link like this , http://127.0.0.1/Client/jakir.php .
127.0.0.1 use as my localhost ip . my operation system is windows8.1 .
Now suggest me,What can I do  .

Comment: Yes, and that is wrong, as I've mentioned in the answer. Networking 101 tells you that `127.0.0.1` is the localhost, which unless your PHP file and MySQL database are running in your Android device (hint, it isn't), then that's not correct